# SQL get boolean value from varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get my result as either 1 or 0 based on if the column `note` is empty or not

column is a `varchar` and i want the result from the query to give me a `boolean` value for that column `note`

```
SELECT id, product, note FROM myTABLE
```

what i tired is,

```
SELECT id, product, CASE WHEN ISNULL(note) THEN 0 ELSE 1 FROM myTable
```

but i am getting an error... i am sure there is simple fix to this i am missing so please help. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT id, product,CASE WHEN note IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as SomeColumn
FROM myTable
```

to check for blank and null as well, use NULLIF

```
SELECT id, product,
CASE WHEN NULLIF(note,'') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as SomeColumn
FROM myTable
```

Comment: ahhh silly me forgot the `END`, thanks for the simple fix, i will mark as answer once the 10min is up. Thank you!

Comment: Also notice IS NULL instead of ISNULL()

Comment: oh I noticed an issue, if the column is empty instead of being null it still returns 1. how can i get 0 if column empty or null

Comment: nvm ignore the comment, above i just need to add OR statement and check. anyways my final query looks like this: `SELECT id, product, CASE WHEN note IS NULL OR note = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SomeColumn FROM myTable`

Comment: You can use NULLIF(Note,'') to return NULL if it is blank